# Get the top selling product's current inventory in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the top selling product's current inventory from the database. I have successfully fetch the top-selling products but unable to fetch their current inventory in the same query.

```
SELECT product_name, product_code, SUM(qty) As TotalQuantity FROM `order_items` GROUP BY product_code ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC LIMIT 5
```

inventory table is something like that

[image]

if you need more info i will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the table is `inventory`. I use a correlated subquery to get current inventory value

```
SELECT oi.product_name, oi.product_code,
SUM(oi.qty) AS TotalQuantity,
(SELECT SUM(inv.qty) FROM `inventory` AS inv WHERE inv.product_code = oi.product_code) AS CurrentStock
FROM `order_items` AS oi
GROUP BY oi.product_code
ORDER BY TotalQuantity DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Its not working when i am trying to add inventory to other outlet too

Comment: what do you mean by other outlet ? can you give information of all the other tables. give CREATE TABLE syntax for the name and some sample data

Comment: I just updated the image attached in question here UD0002 is having 3 inventory

Comment: @Travelers as per the image, it is showing `qty` field's value as **2** for `product_code` **UD0002**

Comment: it should return 3 but above query gives 2 inventory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178003/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-travelers).